# Nested hash_map operations in C++ seems to have different results as I expected

Tags: c++, hashmap, nested

I'm low in C++ and now learning to use the hash_map in STL. When I test nested hash_map in the following toy codes it seems work:

```
#include <hash_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"h4 h5"<<endl;
    hash_map<int,int&> h4;
    int temp=0;
    h4.insert(pair<int,int&>(0,temp));

    hash_map<int, hash_map<int,int&>> h5;
    h5.insert(pair<int, hash_map<int,int&>>(1,h4));
    hash_map<int, hash_map<int,int&>>::iterator h5_itor=h5.find(1);
    h5_itor->second.find(0)->second++;
    h5_itor->second.find(0)->second++;
    h5_itor->second.find(0)->second++;
    cout<<h5.find(1)->second.find(0)->second<<endl;
    int temp2=7;
    h5.find(1)->second.insert(pair<int,int&>(3,temp2));
    h5.find(1)->second.find(3)->second+=100;

    hash_map<int, hash_map<int,int&>>::iterator h5_itor2;
    for(h5_itor2=h5.begin();h5_itor2!=h5.end();h5_itor2++)
    {
       hash_map<int,int&> submap=h5_itor2->second;
       hash_map<int,int&>::iterator submap_itor;
       for(submap_itor=submap.begin();submap_itor!=submap.end();submap_itor++)
       {
            cout<<submap_itor->first<<" -> "<<submap_itor->second<<endl;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is (both in Visual C++ 2010 and Linux):
h4 h5
3
0 -> 3
3 -> 107

But in my real application, as in follows:

```
int main()
{
    int Rq=40;
    int T=10;
    hash_map<int, hash_map<int, int&>> tsMap;
    for(int j=0;j<Rq;j++)
    {
        cout<<">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #"<<j<<endl;
        //int vr=rand()%15;
        for(int t=1;t<=T;t++)
        {
            if(true)
            {
                double ran=rand()/(RAND_MAX*1.0);
                int vr=rand()%5;
                if(tsMap.find(vr)!=tsMap.end())
                {
                    if(tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)!=tsMap.find(vr)->second.end())
                    {
                        cout<<"case a) update "<<vr<<" -> "<<t<<" ->* "<<tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)->second;
                        tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)->second++;
                        cout<<" to "<<tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)->second<<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //hash_map<int, hash_map<int, int&>>::iterator tsMap_itor=tsMap.find(vr);
                        hash_map<int, int&> submap=tsMap.find(vr)->second;
                        int count=1;
                        submap.insert(pair<int,int&>(t,count));
                        cout<<"case b) insert "<<vr<<" -> "<<t<<" ->* "<<tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)->second<<endl;
                    }
                }
                else//
                {
                    hash_map<int, int&> submap;
                    int count=1;
                    submap.insert(pair<int,int&>(t,count));
                    tsMap.insert(pair<int, hash_map<int, int&>>(vr,submap));
                    cout<<"case c) insert "<<vr<<" ->* "<<t<<" -> "<<tsMap.find(vr)->second.find(t)->second<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code terminates without any suggestions (i.e, print less than 10 lines) with case b) (of course and case a)) never performed. I doubt there's something wrong with case b), however the logic is same as the toy code thus I cannot figure it out by just testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is in these lines of code:

```
int count=1;
submap.insert(pair<int,int&>(t,count));
```

You are taking a reference to a local variable that is going out of scope. This is undefined behavior and may be the cause of your problem.

Consider changing your hashmap to `<int,int>` unless you really need references there. If you need references, you will need to ensure that the objects you are referring to do not go out of scope.

The reason it works in your small test code is that `test` and `test2` stay in scope for the lifetime of `main`.

Edit: Another problem is in case 'b' - you add the new item to a local copy `submap`, so it does not get added to the main hash_map. You could use a reference here, I think, so the hash_map gets updated in place.:

```
hash_map<int, int&> &submap=tsMap.find(vr)->second;
--------------------^
```

Comment: Seems that I declare count as a global variable but the problem still occurs.:-( The reason I use a reference here is that, I found if I don't use it, in nested hash_map the count can not be updated at all, though it works in a hash_map.

Comment: Making count a global variable means that all of your hashes will point to the same count. Note: The best tool to find your problem is the debugger (I should have started off saying this). Visual Studio will let you step through the lines one by one and look at the contents of your variables.